# Javascript not running in Flask template

Tags: javascript, html

part of `templates/index.html`

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
var seconds = 0;
var el = document.getElementById('seconds-counter');

function incrementSeconds() {
    seconds += 1;
    el.innerText = "Online for " + seconds + " seconds.";
}

window.onload = function(){
alert("Bot Online");
setInterval(incrementSeconds, 1000);
}
</script>
<body>
<div id='seconds-counter'>0</div>
</body>
```

`keep_alive.py`

```py
from flask import Flask, render_template
from threading import Thread

app = Flask('')

@app.route('/')
def main():
    return render_template('index.html')

def run():
    app.run(host="0.0.0.0", port=8080)
    
def keep_alive():
    server = Thread(target=run)
    server.start()
```

the window alerts but doesn't start the counter.
for context, this is a discord bot being hosted on replit.
any reason why this doesn't work?

Comment: HTML is parsed top to bottom.  When you define "el", it hasn't been drawn on the page yet, so "el" is null.  Try putting your script tag after the div.

Comment: @James Worked. Post this as an answer?

Comment: There are a lot of complete answers available in the dupe link. ^^  Initially it wasn't clear that was the problem you were having.

Comment: I thought this issue was because of Flask because I have never encountered this error before. Thanks anyways.